# How to animate a horizontal D3 bar chart?

Tags: d3.js

I am currently working with this D3 bar chart: http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/faf62e91e3c70a99a306 I would like to simply animate the chart on page load, to fill from left to right. I have seen other snippets of .transform around but cannot seem to grok how to add the animation to my chart correctly. Anyone mind having a look? Whenever I make changed locally (I have basically the same chart installed in my web app) the chart disappears completely and it looks like I have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: What about giving an initial width of 0 to your bars and then transition the bars' width to the width that you are currently giving them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For transitioning from left to right, you just need to set the initial width to zero and the, after `transition()`, to its final value:

```
 bar.append("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+labelWidth+", 0)")
        .attr("height", barHeight)
        .attr("width", 0)//this is the initial value
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)//time in ms
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return scale(d.value);
        });//now, the final value
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8v88gwqn/

Also, you can use a delay to transition each bar separately:

```
    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+labelWidth+", 0)")
        .attr("height", barHeight)
        .attr("width", 0)
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .delay(function(d,i){ return i*250})//a different delay for each bar
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return scale(d.value);
        });
```

Here is the fiddle with the delay: https://jsfiddle.net/8v88gwqn/1/